# KeyError with dict.fromkeys() and dict-like object

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python, you can use a dictionary as the first argument to `dict.fromkeys()`, e.g.:

```
In [1]: d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

In [2]: dict.fromkeys(d)
Out[2]: {'a': None, 'b': None}
```

I tried to do the same with a dict-like object, but that always raises a `KeyError`, e.g.:

```
In [1]: class SemiDict:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.d = {}
   ...:
   ...:     def __getitem__(self, key):
   ...:         return self.d[key]
   ...:
   ...:     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
   ...:         self.d[key] = value
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: sd = SemiDict()

In [3]: sd['a'] = 1

In [4]: dict.fromkeys(sd)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

C:\bin\Console2\<ipython console> in <module>()

C:\bin\Console2\<ipython console> in __getitem__(self, key)

KeyError: 0
```

What exactly is happening here? And can it be resolved, other than using something like `dict.fromkeys(sd.d)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create the dict, `fromkeys` iterates over its argument. So it must be an iterator. One way to make it work is to add an `__iter__` method to your `dict`-like:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.d)
```

Comment: it should be added, that in the absence of `__iter__`, it will access it like a sequence, calling `__getitem__(0)`, then 1, and so on. Thereby the KeyError for 0.

Comment: The default behaviour for __iter__ is to return item[0] item[1] item[2]... which is what is causing the exception you are seeing

Comment: @gnibbler - Pretty sure the default behavior for `iter` is to return an iterator, which will be accessed with calls to its `next()` method until it throws a `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: Works a treat, plus I actually understand the exception now. Many thanks!

Comment: gnibbler is correct in that iter() on this class returns some kind of iterator object. This object in turn calls `__getitem__` as I said. Without a defined length, the iterator would be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

instance of `SemiDict` is not a sequence. I'd imagine the most obvious solution would be to inherit from `dict`, why don't you do it?

Comment: inheriting from `dict` is not very useful, since if you define special behaviour on `__getitem__` , using the methods  `.get()` , `.pop()` , `.popitem()` , `items()` , and others, will **bypass** your custom `__getitem__` behaviour, so you end up rewriting all methods anyway.

Comment: while this might just an example, OP doesn't exactly seem to overwrite default `__getitem__`

Comment: and you **should** rewrite all methods according to docs: *It is also recommended that mappings provide the methods `keys()`, `values()`, `items()`, `get()`, `clear()`, `setdefault()`, `pop()`, `popitem()`, `copy()`, and `update()` behaving similar to those for Python’s standard dictionary objects.* http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types

Comment: Yeah, my point is, just inherit from `UserDict` instead of `dict` so you don't have to repeat yourself.

Comment: You're right, this would work for the simple example I used. Since the 'real' class is somewhat more complicated, I'll go with the `__iter__` solution. Thanks!